# Mysql 'LEFT JOIN' for "exec_SELECTquery" in typo3 version 6.2

Tags: php, mysql, typo3-6.2.x

I have a query

```
$query = 'SELECT DATETIME, message, username
            FROM t_messages
            LEFT OUTER JOIN fe_users ON t_jobs_messages.sendto = fe_users.uid
            WHERE t_messages.uid =25;
```

I need to convert it to `exec_SELECTquery` style.
like

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']>exec_SELECTquery('message, username','t_messages','t_category','t_messages.uid =25');
```

How can I use LEFT OUTER JOIN in the above format.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found an answer.

```
$select_fields ='DATETIME, message, username';
$from_table    ='t_messages LEFT OUTER JOIN fe_users ON t_jobs_messages.sendto = fe_users.uid';
$where_clause  ='t_messages.uid =25';
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery($select_fields, $from_table, $where_clause);
```

Its working for me.
Thank you.